# Variable Change Double Integral (No aproximations)

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

Exact value of $\int_0^1\int_{1-y}^{2-y}\  {\frac 1y}\ e^{-\frac {x}y}\ e^{-y} dxdy$

After taking the antiderivate with respect to ${x}$ and using rectangles, the value is aproximately 0.15
Answer must be between 0 and 1 (probability)

Any suggestions of what variable change should i use?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you could find an analytical solution. As you did
$$\int {\frac 1y}\ e^{-\frac {x}y}\ e^{-y}\, dx=-e^{-\frac{x}{y}-y}$$
$$\int_{1-y}^{2-y}\  {\frac 1y}\ e^{-\frac {x}y}\ e^{-y}\, dx=e^{-y-\frac{1}{y}+1}-e^{-y-\frac{2}{y}+1}$$ which I do not see how to integrate even using special functions.

So, as you did, numerical integration. Using methods supposed to be much more accurate than rectangles, the result is $0.150010$ !